# Named pipes in C reading weird result

Tags: c, windows, pipe, named-pipes

I'm implementing my first program using named pipes in C on windows.
I'm trying to implement Monte Carlo method for number pi.

When creating random numbers everything is generated fine. Then I send numbers and receive it on main thread.

There, somehow, data looks very weird..

It seems the problem is in ConnectNamedPipe as it returns false
Also if I change all the path's with handles, program hangs at ConnectNamedPipe..
It looks something like this:

```
z:-1.#QNAN0, x:-1.#QNAN0, y:0.000000
z:1.#INF00, x:310579431956368060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:0.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:0.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:0.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:0.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:-0.000000, y:0.000000
z:1.#INF00, x:833189623448552210000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:0.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:0.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:0.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:0.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:0.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:0.000000, y:0.000000
z:1.#INF00, x:315573513832673330000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000, y:0.000000
z:-1.#QNAN0, x:-1.#QNAN0, y:0.000000
z:1.#INF00, x:835455692328165330000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:0.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:0.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:0.000000, y:0.000000
z:4.000000, x:2.000000, y:0.000000
z:0.000000, x:0.000000, y:0.000000
```

when it should be something like:

z:4.00000 x:0.475953, y:0.983213

Here is the code for the thread where the numbers are being generated:

```
 HANDLE readpipe, writepipe;

    int a;
    BOOL   fConnected = FALSE; 
    LPTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe1"); 


  unsigned int __stdcall stage1(void * param) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("creating...\n");
    writepipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        lpszPipename, // name of the pipe
        PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND, // 1-way pipe -- send only
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE, 
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, 
        1024, 
        1024, 
        0, // use default wait time
        NULL // use default security attributes
    );
    printf("created...\n");
     fConnected = ConnectNamedPipe("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe1", NULL) ? 
         TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED); 

         if(!fConnected)
         {
            printf("Not working...");
         }
    printf("connected...\n");
    double y[a];
    DWORD length;
    double x[a];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) 
    {
        x[i] = ((double)rand()) / (double)RAND_MAX;
        y[i] = ((double)rand()) / (double)RAND_MAX;
        printf("%f  %f\n",x[i],y[i]);

    }
    printf("writing...\n");

    /*PIPE*/
    WriteFile( writepipe, x, sizeof(x), &length, 0);
    WriteFile( writepipe, y, sizeof(y), &length, 0);
    CloseHandle( writepipe );
    /*PIPE*/


    return 0;
}
```

and here is the main thread:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    srand (time(NULL));

    /*PIPE*/
    HANDLE thread1,thread2;

    /*CreatePipe( &readpipe, &writepipe, 0, 0 );*/
    /*PIPE*/

    thread1 = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( 0, 0, &stage1, 0, 0, 0 );
    WaitForSingleObject( thread1, INFINITE );
    printf("reading.1111..\n");
    CloseHandle(thread1);
    readpipe = CreateFile( lpszPipename, GENERIC_READ,0,               NULL,           OPEN_EXISTING,  0,NULL); 
    DWORD length;
    double x[a];
    double y[a];
    printf("reading...\n");

    ReadFile( readpipe, x, sizeof(x), &length, 0);
    ReadFile( readpipe, y, sizeof(y), &length, 0 );

    double z = 0.0;
    int n=0;
    int N=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        z = x[i] * x[i] + y[i] * y[i];
        printf("z:%f, x:%f, y:%f\n",z,x[i],y[i]);
        if (z < 1) {
            n++;
        }
        N++;
    }

    CloseHandle( readpipe );

    printf("%d %d\n",n,N);
    double result = ((double)n / (double)N) * 4;
    printf("%f\n", result);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fromat your question properly please, it's a double effort to read it and then to try to help you.

Comment: Format your code please, the indentation is very uneven. Where is the function that reads your numbers? What is your actual question?

Comment: Well I have never used named pipes on windows, and I cant figure out what the problem is... function for sending is WriteFile..

Comment: It is not clear how the array size, `a` is being set in the generating code.  That's crucial since it controls how the writing occurs.  The server gets its value of `a` from the command line arguments via `atoi()`.  You don't check any of the I/O operations for success, so you don't know whether they worked.

Comment: It seems the problem is in ConnectNamedPipe as it returns false...

Comment: `ConnectNamedPipe` takes a *handle*, not a string. I'm not sure how your code even compiles like this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @AndrewMedico yeah, when I pass writepipe - which is a handle, the program hangs at ConnectNamedPipe...

Comment: You can't fix a hang by introducing a type error.

Comment: It looks like you've written a deadlock. You're connecting the named pipe synchronously (with a blocking call), but the reader doesn't try to attach until the writer thread exits. Hence the connect never completes.

Comment: So, what should I do know?

Comment: Re-write your code to eliminate the type errors and deadlock. Reading the documentation may help. There is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the documentation you can refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call CreateNamedPipe in main function before you begin your thread. That should work.